# Python script with serial port will run once only

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port

This is my first post.
The following code runs fine in IDLE but when it has finished and run again it gives a permission error... Is this a code error or is there a problem with the hardware and/or driver?

```
   import serial
   import time

   ser = serial.Serial('COM20', 9600, timeout=1)
   print('port open is ' + str(ser.is_open))
   time.sleep(2)
   print('going to close')
   ser.close()
   print('port open is ' + str(ser.is_open))
   time.sleep(2)
```

Result:
port open is True
going to close
port open is False

Error message:
....
....\Python310\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
raise SerialException(
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)

When I Disable/Enable COM20 the program will run again but throws the error when run again.
The comport is a CH340 device, Driver version 3.8.2023.2, no data is sent either way.
It runs under Windows 10.
I tried a reboot, re-installed the driver, assign the port to COM4, used different delays.
Inserted ser.open() at the end of my code which also fails with the same messages on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing an old CH340 driver 3.4.2014.8 (Aug 2014)